# Dual boot with Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 13.04, Ubuntu is low on disk space. What can I do?

Tags: dual-boot, disk-usage, partitioning

Right now, my available disk space on Ubuntu is very low, and I want to increase it. My main drive has several partitions on it. I have a main partition for windows, a 900mb partition which I believe Ubuntu is installed on, and a 13gb partition that contains /home for ubuntu. While running Ubuntu, I got a message that I was low on disk space.

I want to know what my options are. Is it possible for windows and /home to share the same partition? Is there a better way to dual boot ubuntu?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can re-format your computer and put more space for ubuntu. It's not possible that windows and ubuntu use the /home partition, because it has a different filesystem that windows can't use. So, you can use gParted for editing the size of your partitions on a live cd.

Answer (score 0):

You can reformat you HDD/SSD using the following tool: `gparted` and then adjust both partitions to the size you need/want.

If you don't have `gparted` already, please open a terminal window and the copy/paste the following:

`sudo apt-get install gparted`

So there is no need for you to use a LiveCD if you don't have one, as i think `gparted` it's not a heavy program.

Beware to have a backup of all of your files, just in case something goes wrong, which is very rare to happen.

I believe that the main partition where Ubuntu is installed (the 900MiB one) is the one that is causing you trouble.

Try to allocate some more space to the partition where you have Ubuntu installed via GParted. The program is very straightforward to use.

Hope i've helped you.

Nuno Machado

EDIT: Windows and Ubuntu are incompatible on filesystem level, as Windows uses NTFS and Ubuntu EXT filesystem, so logically, they cannot share the same space or partition.
Neither Windows can 'see' EXT filesystems. Luckilly Linux can 'see' NTFS filesystems, as you will see when you use GParted tool.